# Anthos showing wrong status of Deployment on on-premise external cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-anthos

I wanted to give a try to GCP's Anthos On-Premise GKE offering.

For sake of my demo I setup a Kubernetes cluster in GCP itself using Google Compute Engine following instructions from (https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/turnkey/gce/)

[image]

After this I followed Anthos documentation to register my cluster to Anthos. I was able to register the cluster and Login into it using both Token based and Basic authentication based mechanisms.

[image]

Now when I try to deploy anything from GCP console, I get following error

[image]

But the deployment succeeds, I can see deployment and associated pods in Running state on my cluster.

[image]

[image]

Also when I try to deploy using Marketplace I get following error.

[image]

[image]

I wish to know if it is a bug in Anthos or my cluster has some missing configurations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not running Anthos GKE On-Prem, you're running open-source Kubernetes on Google Cloud. Things designed for Anthos - the marketplace and connecting clusters to Cloud Console - are **not supposed to work** in your setup. The fact that they mostly work despite that is an accident (and a testament to the portability and compatibility of Kubernetes).

To get Cloud Console integration and use the marketplace, you need to use either [Anthos GKE On-Prem](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/) that runs on VMWare or regular [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/).

Comment: Thanks.  That does make sense. So I can not just use any vanilla K8S cluster with Anthos ? Is that a correct understanding ? You need special on-premise K8S cluster or GKE ?

Comment: Yes, for Anthos you need a special on-prem cluster or a special cluster on a different cloud provider. GKE is not marketed as Anthos but it's the most complete Kubernetes offering from Google, it does everything Anthos can and more.